# remove index.php in my url in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to remove index.php from my url in zend framework.

This is my URL :-

```
http://localhost/demo/html/index.php/cp
```

But I want like this  `http://localhost/demo/html/cp`

This is code below I am using in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Please provide me a solution for this

Comment: Have you configured a virtual host for your project?

Comment: What server software are you using? Nginx, Apache? What operating system are you using (relevant for location of the hosts file)?